# How to update a record in Hive table using Informatica powercenter

Tags: hive, etl, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics

I'm trying to update a record based on ID field in Hive table using informtica cloud data integration. But the problem is Instead of updating the existing record it is creating new record. Can anyone please suggest better approach

Comment: have you defined keys correctly in informatica target definition and have you defined correct update strategy ? Pls share some mapping screenshot as well

Comment: Yes in iics I'm using below target properties. Target operation: Update update columns: ID field mapping: auto. When i run the mapping task it is creating new record instead of updating. I found few articles that through iics cdi or powercenter we can't update or delete records in Hive. Is that true ?? Could you please share your inputs

Comment: As per the docs: https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration-connectors/current-version/hive-connector/mappings-and-mapping-tasks-with-hive-connector/hive-targets-in-mappings.html Update is a supported operation. Can you share the referenced articles?

Comment: Thank you. As per this doc Mapping should run in Adavanced mode